# How to make colored images in IE 11 gray

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, grayscale

Is there a way to make colored images gray in IE 11? In 9-10 it works using the svg filter, but not in 11.

My code below

```
    img {
      filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
      filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. See [Grayscale color not working in IE 11 Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41939391/1016716), [Grayscale in IE 10 and 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26002324/1016716), [Cross-browser (IE 10 & 11) grayscale issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23396267/1016716) etc.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted. Is there a simple solution that I just don't see?

Answer (score -3):

IE specific filter should stand last and IE should be in quirk mode ...

```
 img.grayscale {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
        filter: gray;
    }
```